# One Item from ListView not displayed at all (initially, and when reused)

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I use a custom `ArrayAdapter` with this `getView` method :

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView == null)
        {
        LayoutParams lp;

            convertView = new RelativeLayout(context);
            convertView.setLayoutParams(
                new AbsListView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 60));

            //--> line
            //----> serial
            TextView serial = new TextView(context);
            serial.setId(0x01);
            serial.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            serial.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            lp = new LayoutParams(parent.getWidth()>>3,(int)(75*coeff_height));
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
            serial.setLayoutParams(lp);
            serial.setTag("serial");
            ((RelativeLayout)convertView).addView(serial);
            //----> profil
            TextView profil = new TextView(context);
            profil.setId(0x02);
            profil.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            profil.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            lp = new LayoutParams(parent.getWidth()>>3,(int)(75*coeff_height));
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, serial.getId());
            profil.setLayoutParams(lp);
            profil.setTag("profil");
            ((RelativeLayout)convertView).addView(profil);
            //----> modified
            TextView modified = new TextView(context);
            modified.setId(0x08);
            modified.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            modified.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            lp = new LayoutParams(parent.getWidth()>>3,(int)(75*coeff_height));
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, created.getId());
            modified.setLayoutParams(lp);
            modified.setTag("modified");
            ((RelativeLayout)convertView).addView(modified);
        }

        //set content
        ((TextView)convertView.findViewWithTag("serial")).setText(""+position);
        ((TextView)convertView.findViewWithTag("profil")).setText("profil");
        ((TextView)convertView.findViewWithTag("modified")).setText("Dernière modification");
        System.out.println("END Position "+position+" // "+convertView);

        return convertView;
}
```

When my `ListView` is displayed the first item (initially) or item corresponding to a reused of this first `View` (recycled View) are not displayed. The content of the view is empty. All other view are correctly display.

Any idea about this problem?

Edit : more information at 17:40 13 mars (UTC+1)

I simplify the source code like this :

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    System.out.println("parent = "+parent.getClass());

    if(convertView == null)
    {
        LayoutParams lp;

        convertView = new RelativeLayout(context);
        //----> serial
        TextView serial = new TextView(context);
        serial.setId(0x01);
        serial.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        serial.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        lp = new LayoutParams(parent.getWidth()>>3,(int)(75*coeff_height));
        serial.setLayoutParams(lp);
        serial.setTag("serial");
        ((LinearLayout)convertView).addView(serial);
    }

    //set content
    ((TextView)convertView.findViewWithTag("serial")).setText(""+position);

    return convertView;
}
```

The problem still exit.

Bit if I change and use this code :

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    System.out.println("parent = "+parent.getClass());

    if(convertView == null)
    {
        LayoutParams lp;

        convertView = new TextView(context);
    }

    //set content
    convertView.setText(""+position);

    return convertView;
}
```

There are no problem. All item appeared correctly. It seems the problem come from instantiate ViewGroup object during the first call to getView. I will try inflating a xml layout. But As I say in previous comment, I need to specify dynamically height and width of child view.

Cordially,
CC

Comment: you are giving text color white and I didnt find any background color so may be white on white

Comment: why would you create the row in code, instead of xml? this just looks awful.

Comment: inflating xml will make it easy to understand and debug

Comment: @vs-thaakur : I have a blue picture background define in my Actvity. MOre, the text is perfectly readable for other item (build from the same adapter).

Comment: @Daniel Bo : in xml template we can't define calculated width and height for child view. Maybe I just don't known about it.

Comment: you cant calculate it, thats right, but you can set the height in code and define in xml. if you really have to calculate it, usually setting a row to wrap content in height (talking about vertical listviews) is sufficient. i dont know why you have to calculate the dimensions

Comment: @Daniel Bo : for width I display 8 different information. So how in xml I can define for each textview of my row un width of 1/8 of the parent?

Comment: @vs.thaakur : inflating xml xml it's work correctly, but I do some test to understand, and I have the same problem when adding view into the linearlayout that have been inflated.

Comment: As I said yesterday inflating xml work correctly but when I make width modification of child view, my problem appear again. All line are correctly display except one where new width parameter aren't applied. The problem persist when the view is recycled.

Comment: you can add weights to every piece of information 1 meins 100% 0.5 50% of space, if 2 views are in one layout each weight 0.5, each will take up half the space. so 0.125 should do the trick in your case.

Comment: @Daniel Bo : Perfect this work correctly. Even if I don't like to not understand why it work only this way. thank you

Comment: im guessing there is some sort of error in your code, which prevents the information from being set during initialization. but thats too much code to read :p